# MFC: CListCtrl LVS_SORTASCENDING not working?

Tags: winapi, mfc, clistctrl, comctl32

I'm not sure why something so simple doesn't seem to work?   I have a `CFormView` with a `CListCtrl` member variable that uses DDX.    The Dialog already has the *Ascending* sort option set in the resource editor, but I even force it with `ModifyStyle()` it still doesn't sort, my added item always ends up at the end of the list.  Groups are enabled, so not sure if that's causing an issue, but basically here's what I do below.  Any ideas?

```
// have class with the CListCtrl and DDX
class CMyView : public CFormView
{
 public:
  CListCtrl m_MyList;
};

// init the CListCtrl
void CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    __super::OnInitialUpdate();
    
    m_MyList.ModifyStyle(0, LVS_SORTASCENDING);
    
    if (m_MyList.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount()==0) {
        // add our columns
        m_MyList.InsertColumn(0, _T("The Column"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 500);
        // enable groups
        m_MyList.EnableGroupView(TRUE);
        // add our groups
        LVGROUP lvg={};
        lvg.cbSize = sizeof(lvg);
        lvg.mask = LVGF_HEADER|LVGF_GROUPID;

        lvg.pszHeader = _T("Group Header 1");
        lvg.iGroupId++;
        if (m_MyList.InsertGroup(-1, &lvg)>=0) {
            m_Group1=lvg.iGroupId;
        }

        lvg.pszHeader = _T("Group Header 2");
        lvg.iGroupId++;
        if (m_MyList.InsertGroup(-1, &lvg)>=0) {
            m_Group2=lvg.iGroupId;
        }
    }

};

// adding item ends up at the end of the list - NOT sorted
void CMyView::AddListItem(const TCHAR* str)
{
    LVITEM lvi={};
    lvi.mask|=LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_IMAGE|LVIF_PARAM|LVIF_GROUPID;
    lvi.pszText=const_cast<TCHAR*>(str);
    lvi.lParam=0;
    lvi.iImage=ICONidxSomething;
    lvi.iGroupId=m_Group1;
    lvi.iItem=m_MyList.GetItemCount();
    m_MyList.InsertItem(&lvi);
}
```

Comment: `LVS_SORTASCENDING` and `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` only work in `LVS_LIST` and `LVS_REPORT` mode.

Comment: refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles#remarks

Answer (score 0):

According to [the explanation in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles#remarks).

> For the `LVS_SORTASCENDING` and `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` styles, item indexes
> are sorted based on item text in ascending or descending order,
> respectively. Because the `LVS_LIST` and `LVS_REPORT` views display items
> in the same order as their indexes, the results of sorting are
> immediately visible to the user. The `LVS_ICON` and `LVS_SMALLICON` views
> do not use item indexes to determine the position of icons. With those
> views, the results of sorting are not visible to the user.

We need to set the correct List View properties.

```
LONG lstyle;
//Get the style of the current listctrl
lstyle = GetWindowLong(m_MyList.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE); 
//clear display
lstyle &= ~LVS_TYPEMASK;
//set style
lstyle |= LVS_REPORT;
SetWindowLong(m_MyList.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lstyle);
```

OR change in VS Properties window.

[image]

Comment: It was already in report view - setup on the control in the resource editor.  I gave up on why it wasn't working and just created a `m_MyList.SortItemsEx(ListCompareFunc, (LPARAM)&m_MyList);` that I call on each addition and that worked.